# WPF C# で DataGrid の Columns, Row, Cell を取得する方法

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-datagrid

WPF で `DataGrid.Rows` が見つからず苦労しています。

以下の方法で DataGrid の内容を取得できましたが、もっとシンプルな方法があると思っています。 `Columns["name"]` のように特定の列を指定して取得する方法もわかりますでしょうか。

`dg` は XAML の `<DataGrid x:Name=...>` です。

```
   for (int i = 0; i < dg.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < dg.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                TextBlock cellContent = dg.Columns[j].GetCellContent(row) as TextBlock;
                Console.WriteLine(cellContent.Text);
            }
    }
```

Comment: 本来的な話をするとコードビハインド(.xaml.cs)で操作するのではなく、MVVMパターンに倣い、対応するViewModel側でDataTableなどに双方向バインディングして、そちらで操作するのが良いと思います。

Comment: 考え方自体が違っているんですね。
ありがとうございます。